# SQL DISTINCT based on a single column, but keep all columns as output

Tags: sql, join, distinct, teradata

```
--mytable
col1 col2 col3
1    A    red
2    A    green
3    B    purple
4    C    blue
```

Let's call the table above `mytable`. I want to select *only* distinct values from `col2`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 col2
FROM
 mytable
```

When I do this the output looks like this, which is expected:

```
col2
A
B
C
```

but how do I perform the same type of query, yet keep all columns? The output would look like below. In essence I'm going through `mytable` looking at `col2`, and when there's multiple occurrences of `col2` I'm *only* keeping the first row.

```
col1 col2 col3
1    A    red
3    B    purple
4    C    blue
```

Do SQL functions (eg `DISTINCT`) have arguments I could set? I could imagine it to be something like `KeepAllColumns = TRUE` for this DISTINCT function? Or do I need to perform `JOIN`s to get what I want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using Teradata which uses the _"Teradata Vantage Advanced SQL Engine"_. I hope that answers your question and here's a little more should it be needed https://www.teradata.com/Products/Software/Database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions, particularly `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col2) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

`row_number()` enumerates the rows, starting with "1".  You can control whether you get the oldest, earliest, biggest, smallest . . .

Comment: @JasonHunter . . . I see that you do provide a table name in the question, so I updated the answer.

Comment: getting closer... but now I'm getting error _"Object 'mytable' does not exist"_. Maybe the syntax isn't supported by my Teradata SQL database? Any workaround? https://www.teradata.com/Products/Software/Database

Comment: @JasonHunter . . . That is the name you used in your question.  You need to use the correct table name.  This syntax is supported by Teradata -- it is standard SQL syntax.

Comment: you are correct and it's now working as expected. How do I control whether I get the oldest, earliest, biggest, smallest? Do I change the integer value of the `seqnum = x` argument to whatever value I please? Not sure I understand that part exactly.

Comment: @JasonHunter . . . You change the `order by` for the column(s) that specify earliest and so on.

Comment: sorry I'm a SQL rookie... so I just issue an `ORDER BY column_name` before running the code that you suggest? Is it just that easy?

Comment: @JasonHunter . . . The `order by` in the windowing clause.  Yes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `QUALIFY` clause in Teradata:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM mytable
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY col2) = 1 -- Get 1st row per group
```

If you want to change the ordering for how to determine which `col2` row to get, just change the expression in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select m.* from mytable m
where not exists (
  select 1 from mytable
  where col2 = m.col2 and col1 < m.col1
)
```

This code will return the rows for which there is not another row with the same `col2` and a smaller value in `col1`.